# Regex renaming group capture

Tags: regex, file-rename

With Regex how to capture the spaces in the `{}` brackets so I can insert a comma between the words?

I tried the following but it doesn't capture the white-space in the brackets.

```
(((.*)((\[.*\])\s(\(.*\))\s)(\{.+\s\})))

\3\4
```

input:

```
fruit apple [red wine] (sake) {jam hammer water knife salt}
```

output:

```
fruit apple [orange] (sake) {jam, hammer, water, knife, salt}
```

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: PCRE 1 which the bulk rename utility uses

Comment: Try it like this `(?:{|\G(?!^))\S+\K\h(?=[^{}]*})` and replace with a comma and space https://regex101.com/r/OOXj3U/1

Comment: It needs to be able to capture all other text in groups to work. Is it possible?

Comment: You can capture those other groups like this `(?:([^][]*)(\[[^][]*])\h+(\([^()]*\))\h+{|\G(?!^))\S+\K\h(?=[^{}]*})`  https://regex101.com/r/om6ZXd/1

Comment: Doesn't work since all the text in the string needs a group including the spaces in the string.

Comment: And if you group `(\S+)` into group 4 also? https://regex101.com/r/BZjDtV/1

Comment: it needs to look something like this in groups. https://regex101.com/r/om6ZXd/2

Comment: Not sure if you can do it in one step. Perhaps you can first use the first pattern https://regex101.com/r/OOXj3U/1 to add the comma's, then then use https://regex101.com/r/lKG6HS/1 to get all 4 groups

Comment: I know this isn't my question, but is there any chance you could explain why in your comment on Jul 27 you have `(?:{|\G(?!^))` in there? I'm trying to understand that part for my own edification and just don't get why it's necessary. @Thefourthbird

Comment: @aaaa The `\G` anchors matches at 2 positions, either at the start of the string or at the end of the previous match. As it should not start at the beginning of the string, you can use a negative lookahead `(?!^)` to assert that the position is not at the start of the string. Then you first match `{`, after that it matches all the non whitespace chars and clears the match buffer using `\K` leaving `\h` to match the horizontal whitespace char we want.

Comment: I think I get that, but why was it needed for this user's answer? Does `\S+\K\h(?=[^{}]*})` fail to meet some condition that I'm not seeing? Was looking at this specifically: https://regex101.com/r/SUZfhH/1 [before the OP added extra conditions] @Thefourthbird

Comment: @aaaa That would indeed match the spaces between the curly's, but I looked at the pattern of the OP and saw this `\[.*\]` followed by `\(.*\)` and thought that that should also be part of the pattern. I included that in the pattern, but you also want to match an unknown amount of spaces between the curly's, that is why I used the `\G` This for example would not work https://regex101.com/r/Tnp3gd/1

Comment: Ah, okay. That's going to take me some time to digest, but really appreciate the thoughtful response. I'm just trying to improve.